# Unable upload a file in Email format using slack API

Tags: slack-api

even when the filetype is passed as "email",
the file is uploaded as plain/text file

```
const request = require("request");

async function main(){
  await request.post(
    {
      url: 'https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
      formData: {
        token: 'xoxb-token',
        tile: 'Email',
        filename: 'test_email',
        filetype: 'email',
        channels: 'C012345ABCD',
        content: 'email_content_html'
`
      }
    },
    async function (err, response) {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        // just for debugging
        console.log(response.body);
      }
    }
  );

}

main();
```

the above code gives the response:
`{"ok":true,"file":{"id":"asdfasdfas","created":asdfasdfasd,"timestamp":asdfasdf,"name":"test_email.txt","title":"test email","mimetype":"text\/plain","filetype":"text","pretty_type":"Plain text","user":"asdfasdfasdf","user_team":"asdfasdfasdf","editable":true,"size":29262,"mode":"snippet","is_external":false,"external_type":"","is_public":true,"public_url_shared":false,"display_as_bot":false,"username":"","url_private":"https:\/\/files.slack.com\/files-pri\/asdfasdf-asdfasdf\/test_email.txt","url_private_download":"https:\/\/files.slack.com\/files-pri\/adsfasdf-adsfasdf\/download\/test_email.txt",.........."groups":[],"ims":[],"has_more_shares":false,"has_rich_preview":false,"file_access":"visible"}}`

It never shows email snippet no matter what I pass as "content"

Answer (score 0):

The `email` `filetype` requires some specific logic that's only accessible by Slack's custom built integrations, I'm afraid.

As an alternative, you could create a text file or a pdf, and then upload it to Slack.